Does Precompile Address Affect State Root?
I'm currently building my own L2 stack and have encountered an issue with the state root. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I used the eth_getProof API to get an address proof for a specific precompiled address. However, the validation fails every time I try to verify the proof using the state root, address, and address proof with a specific block number.
Below code is about validating proof.
from web3 import Web3
from eth_utils import (
    keccak,
)
import rlp
from rlp.sedes import (
    Binary,
    big_endian_int,
)
from trie import (
    HexaryTrie,
)
from web3._utils.encoding import (
    pad_bytes,
)

httpUrl = "http://localhost:8545"

# Create a temperoray trie object base on the proof
def format_proof_nodes(proof):
    trie_proof = []
    for rlp_node in proof:
        trie_proof.append(rlp.decode(bytes(rlp_node)))
    return trie_proof

def verify_eth_get_proof(proof, root):
    # Initialize the trie
    trie_root = Binary.fixed_length(32, allow_empty=True)
    hash32 = Binary.fixed_length(32)

    #Create account object
    class _Account(rlp.Serializable):
        fields = [
                    ('nonce', big_endian_int),
                    ('balance', big_endian_int),
                    ('storage', trie_root),
                    ('code_hash', hash32)
                ]
    acc = _Account(
        proof.nonce, proof.balance, proof.storageHash, proof.codeHash
    )

    # Create the key value pair from account object
    rlp_account = rlp.encode(acc)
    
    trie_key = keccak(bytes.fromhex(proof.address[2:]))
   
    #Verifying account proof
    assert rlp_account == HexaryTrie.get_from_proof(
        root, trie_key, format_proof_nodes(proof.accountProof)
    ), f"Failed to verify account proof {proof.address}"

    #Verifying storage proof
    for storage_proof in proof.storageProof:
        trie_key = keccak(pad_bytes(b'\x00', 32, storage_proof.key))
        root = proof.storageHash
        if storage_proof.value == b'\x00':
            rlp_value = b''
        else:
            rlp_value = rlp.encode(storage_proof.value) #node data is serialised wit rlp serialization

        # Check correctness of storage value
        assert rlp_value == HexaryTrie.get_from_proof(
            root, trie_key, format_proof_nodes(storage_proof.proof)
        ), f"Failed to verify storage proof {storage_proof.key}"

    return True


w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(httpUrl))

block = w3.eth.get_block("0x78")
proof = w3.eth.get_proof('0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000016', [], "0x78")
isValidProof = verify_eth_get_proof(proof, block.stateRoot)
print(isValidProof)

And I kept running into this error below
raise MissingTrieNode(
trie.exceptions.MissingTrieNode: Trie database is missing hash HexBytes('0x0e425909a04d5c1d9456d61bbaf8456d3bcfd9175d38064ccab8b568972178b4') needed to look up node at prefix (), when searching for key HexBytes('0x542220b0147f4cc0e0156d993334777d699c312c2fe454f8b3fa338ed309f4a0') at root hash HexBytes('0x0e425909a04d5c1d9456d61bbaf8456d3bcfd9175d38064ccab8b568972178b4')


The precompiled address seems to be in the op-stack technology stack. I am sure that there is no problem with your code, because I have tested your code on both the op test network and the mantle test network, and it can be proved to be successful.
...

httpUrl = "https://rpc.sepolia.mantle.xyz"

...

block = w3.eth.get_block("0x423178")
proof = w3.eth.get_proof('0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000016', [], "0x423178")
isValidProof = verify_eth_get_proof(proof, block.stateRoot)
print(isValidProof) 
// True

But if you have a problem locally, it may be that there is something wrong with the L2 you built. It is recommended to check the part of the proof construction in depth. In fact, op-stack itself has a proof of this precompiled contract (L2ToL1MessagePasser.sol). You can refer to the code of op-node: OutputAtBlock to compare where the problem lies.
func (n *nodeAPI) OutputAtBlock(ctx context.Context, number hexutil.Uint64) (*eth.OutputResponse, error) {
    recordDur := n.m.RecordRPCServerRequest("optimism_outputAtBlock")
    defer recordDur()

    ref, status, err := n.dr.BlockRefWithStatus(ctx, uint64(number))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get L2 block ref with sync status: %w", err)
    }

    head, err := n.client.InfoByHash(ctx, ref.Hash)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get L2 block by hash %s: %w", ref, err)
    }
    if head == nil {
        return nil, ethereum.NotFound
    }

    proof, err := n.client.GetProof(ctx, predeploys.L2ToL1MessagePasserAddr, []common.Hash{}, ref.Hash.String())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get contract proof at block %s: %w", ref, err)
    }
    if proof == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("proof %w", ethereum.NotFound)
    }
    // make sure that the proof (including storage hash) that we retrieved is correct by verifying it against the state-root
    if err := proof.Verify(head.Root()); err != nil {
        n.log.Error("invalid withdrawal root detected in block", "stateRoot", head.Root(), "blocknum", number, "msg", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid withdrawal root hash, state root was %s: %w", head.Root(), err)
    }

    var l2OutputRootVersion eth.Bytes32 // it's zero for now
    l2OutputRoot, err := rollup.ComputeL2OutputRootV0(head, proof.StorageHash)
    if err != nil {
        n.log.Error("Error computing L2 output root, nil ptr passed to hashing function")
        return nil, err
    }

    return &eth.OutputResponse{
        Version:               l2OutputRootVersion,
        OutputRoot:            l2OutputRoot,
        BlockRef:              ref,
        WithdrawalStorageRoot: proof.StorageHash,
        StateRoot:             head.Root(),
        Status:                status,
    }, nil
}


Thanks for your reply. I believe there might be an issue with my custom op-stack.
I have one qeustion though.
I made a valid transaction and updated the state trie, but how can I get an 'invalid proof verify' error?

Can you post your proof construction process and compare it with the original proof construction of OP? Maybe you can find something.
